# SQL Server Insert Varbinary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to take a `Varbinary(max)` from a SQL Server column and insert it into another `varbinary` column, however my image does not render when displayed via the new field, what am I doing wrong?

I've copied from SQL Server, ie

```
E7D28201A240202178EF491E413EB4DDBCFB54A15077A989A37A0C5E4E0F143AEE7000CE3F3A70C0E4F342E524C8F4A7243888AA581EC051B030E7A8EF4E233DF.....
```

and then

```
update client
set Photo = convert(varbinary(max),'E7D28201A240202178EF491E413EB4DDBCFB54A15077A989A37A0C5E4E0F143AEE7000CE3F3A70C0E4F342E524C8F4A7243888AA581EC051B030E7A8EF4E233DF.....')
where id='40946b09-81be-42b0-ae62-63182acb1e89'
```

Comment: why not use the "image" datatype designed to take byte arrays of images?

Comment: Hi, sorry this pre existing code and cant start changing formats

Comment: in that case, can i ask why you are converting something if its already in the correct format? as it stands you are converting data into different data - hence why you cant see the image correctly

Comment: @Takarii the image datatype is deprecated and should not be used. The correct datatype for this is varbinary(max). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange I was unaware the format was being depreciated. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Takarii Sorry im not, I have an issue with a production database record, where all I want to do is load the data from a backup database into the production(that field only), so im asking what am I doing wrong\ what is the solution?

Comment: Sorry my sql knowledge is limited, I just want to take whats in backup and update the existing record with the correct data, whats the correct sql statements for this?

Comment: This looks like base64 encoded binary sequence. The idea of this format is to be able to store binary data in text fields. Do you decode it prior rendering the image?

Comment: @nanestev yes i render as so <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.PhotoDisplay)

Comment: Are you sure values in both fields are identical? If you're going to store it in a varbinary field it's better to decode it, because base64 encoding inflates the data by 30% and it will be a problem if you store large amount of images

Comment: @srutzky is right, the string is hex

Answer (score 9):

The data is not [Base64 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) as that would have a much larger range of alpha characters, whereas this value is pure hex values (i.e. 0-9, A-F). Also, the example HTML code provided by the O.P. (in a comment on the Question) is:

```
<img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.PhotoDisplay)
```

which shows that the source value of `Model.PhotoDisplay` is first converted *to* Base64 so that the `data:image;base64` type designation will be correct.

The problem is that SQL Server, when asked to convert the value, does not know that it is already a hex/binary string. You need to tell SQL Server what the format of the source data is. This can be done in two ways:

1. Depending on how you are building this value, you just need to add the `0x` prefix and remove the single-quotes:

   ```sql
   UPDATE cl
   SET    cl.Photo = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 0xE7D28201A24020.....)
   FROM   Client cl
   WHERE  cl.[id] = '40946b09-81be-42b0-ae62-63182acb1e89';
   ```
2. If you need to keep the value as a string, *and* are using SQL Server 2008 or newer, then you can use the "style" option of the [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function to tell SQL Server that it is a binary value, and you have the additional option of

   - adding the `0x` prefix and using a "style" of `1`:

     ```sql
     UPDATE cl
     SET    cl.Photo = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '0xE7D28201A24020.....', 1)
     FROM   Client cl
     WHERE  cl.[id] = '40946b09-81be-42b0-ae62-63182acb1e89';
     ```
   - keep the value without the `0x` prefix and using a "style" of `2`:

     ```sql
     UPDATE cl
     SET    cl.Photo = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 'E7D28201A24020.....', 2)
     FROM   Client cl
     WHERE  cl.[id] = '40946b09-81be-42b0-ae62-63182acb1e89';
     ```

But, if this data really is coming from a `VARBINARY(MAX)` field in another table, then how is it ending up as a string in the first place? The easiest way to move this is to either:

- Transfer the data directly between tables:

  ```sql
  UPDATE cl
  SET    cl.Photo = src.SomeField
  FROM   Client cl
  INNER JOIN SomeTable src
          ON src.JoinField = cl.JoinField
  WHERE something? = somethingElse?;
  ```
- Use a `VARBINARY(MAX)` variable:

  ```sql
  DECLARE @Photo VARBINARY(MAX);

  SELECT @Photo = src.photo
  FROM   SomeTable src
  WHERE  src.SomeField = ?;

  UPDATE cl
  SET    cl.Photo = @Photo
  FROM   Client cl
  WHERE  cl.[id] = '40946b09-81be-42b0-ae62-63182acb1e89';
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Why not copy it directly using an SQL statement, rather than copy/pasting from SSMS?

I'll leave an example to copy the data from another client (bogus `id` for the example):

```
UPDATE client
SET Photo = (SELECT Photo FROM client WHERE id='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
WHERE id='40946b09-81be-42b0-ae62-63182acb1e89';
```